# Expresso Store: Updating product price listing based on current modifier chosen

Tags: add-on, expresso-store, modifiers

I've seen in the documents that you can wrap `<span class="store_product_price"></span>` around the price to make it dynamic. However, I absolutely cannot get this to work. It will display the starting price but will not update the price after you choose a modifier with a price adjustment.

I've also tested this in the store_example templates by wrapping the same span tag around the price list on the product template.

Is there something I am missing to make this work?

Comment: Any JS errors on that page?

Comment: I'm assuming you're using expresso's store addon - is that right? If soit would be a good idea to make that clear in your question...

Comment: No, there are no JS errors on that page. I had a look.

Comment: And yes, I am using the Expression Engine exp:resso store addon. I got here directly from the store support so I had assumed this was specifically for exp:resso Store questions. Good to know otherwise.

Comment: Hmm, is it loading the Store JS files? `/themes/third_party/store/`

Comment: Yes it is. I have checked that and even manually added it myself for a test to double check. The span class wrap WILL output the original price, just not update it. I've also just realized that the store_template product page is also not dynamically displaying or changed the SKU's for the products as well.

Comment: This is tough to diagnose w/o seeing any code. I would head to their official support for more help: https://exp-resso.com/store/support

Answer (score 6):

If you are using version 1.6 or lower of Store there is a known bug with dynamic product variables that was fixed in version 1.6.1. [(Release Notes)](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/release_notes.html#store-1-6-1). Could you update to the latest version of Store and see if the issue still persist.

Comment: I had the same issue. Updating to 1.6.1+ will fix it.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you. I'll give that a go later today and see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: Did that fix the issue for you Robbie?